# Flex: first div has column and next has row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like the following layout but I am constrained by the html code. I can only change the CSS.

Column 1 has a defined width but the rows must take up the rest of the width.

```
+---+----------------+
|   |        2       |
|   |----------------+
| 1 |        3       |
|   |----------------+
|   |        4       |
|---|----------------+
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="c1">1</div>
  <div class="l2">2</div>
  <div class="l3">3</div>
  <div class="l4">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a task for Flexbox but CSS-Grid which can control 2 directions, unlike Flexbox.

To have 2 columns where the first column width is depending on the first element and the remaining to occupy the remaining space you can use: `grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;`.

To make the first element occupy the entire first column you can use `grid-row: span {{number of rows}}`. If you do not know the number of rows or other elements then use an insanely high number that would not be reached:

```css
.cont {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

.c1 {
  grid-row: span 100;
  width: 200px;
}

/* for visualization purpose only */
.cont > div {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="c1">1</div>
  <div class="l2">2</div>
  <div class="l3">3</div>
  <div class="l4">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to use flexboxes to possibly change the order of the lines, with grid it's also possible so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As already @tacoshy mentioned this can be done with grid, and you may have a look into my implementation too.

```css
.cont {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr; 
  width:100px;
  border:1px solid gray
}

.c1 {
  grid-row: 1 / span 4; 
  border:1px solid gray;
  width:30px
}

.l2, .l3, .l4 {
  grid-column: 2;
  border:1px solid gray
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="c1">1</div>
  <div class="l2">2</div>
  <div class="l3">3</div>
  <div class="l4">4</div>
</div>
```